# Extract Redux payload from Actions unit type by action type

Tags: typescript, types, redux

I am trying to extract `payload` from `Actions` union type but don't know whether it's possible in `Typescript`.

So, below is what I want to achieve.

```
type Actions = { type: "INIT", payload: { x: string }} | { type: "CLOSE", payload: { y: number }};


type ExtractPayload<T> = // how to extract payload given action type as `T`


function doSomething<T extends Actions["type"]>(type: T, payload: ExtractPayload<T>) { 
    // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Extarct` conditional type to extract the apropriate Action type from the union and then use a type query to get the type of the `payload` property:

```
type Actions = { type: "INIT", payload: { x: string }} | { type: "CLOSE", payload: { y: number }};


type ExtractPayload<T extends Actions["type"]> = Extract<Actions, {type: T }>['payload']


function doSomething<T extends Actions["type"]>(type: T, payload: ExtractPayload<T>) { 
    // ... 
}

doSomething("INIT", { x: "" }) //ok
doSomething("INIT", { x: 1 }) //err
doSomething("CLOSE", { y: 1 }) //ok
doSomething("CLOSE", { y: "1"} ) //err
```

Comment: hm, good one. I tried to `type ExtractPayload<T extends Test["type"]> = Test extends { type: T, payload: infer P } ? P : never
` which is very similar to what `Extract` use under the hood but it always resolves to never, maybe you know why?

Comment: @PawełLula conditional types behave differently when you have named type parameters and unions as opposed to directly the union. Conditional type distribute over naked type parameters and don't distribute directly on the union. You can write it without extract if you introduce a type parameter `type ExtractPayload<T extends Actions["type"]> = Actions extends infer U ? U  extends { type: T, payload: infer P } ? P : never : never`

Comment: @PawełLula you can read about the distribution behavior of conditional type here : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html